# Error -215 trainDescCollection[iIdx] Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, surf, sift

I'm matching two images and in the 80% of the cases works but in some cases it crashes and show up this message:

> ... matches = matcher.match(d1, d2) error:
>   ......\opencv-2.4.6\modules\features2d\src\matchers.cpp:365: error:
>   (-215) trainDescCollection[iIdx].rows < IMGIDX_ONE

where `d1` and `d2` are the descriptors of the two images. I searh in Google but didn't found an answer. Maybe its a stupid error but I'm a noob in this field.

Furthermore I read in this website the following declaration :'it works perfectly just with SIFT and SURF descriptors(which are non free)'. Do you know if SIFT and SURF are protected by copyright?

Thanks all!

Comment: You should consider cleaning up your question a little bit--you are asking two different things.  I would focus more on the technical issue, and provide more details on what exactly you tried and what kinds of images you're trying to match.  Provide more of your code.

Answer (score 6):

This is an open bug in opencv. 
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5700

Try using smaller images (for example, take a subset and/or down-sample). It looks as though the implementation involves a tricky (in the pejorative sense) optimisation which assumed that the number of features (in one of the images) is less than some magic power-of-two.

Answer (score -2):

You have right! I got a tip of the problem (I think). I take the two images where I get the problem and I run the same code in an another Computer. Well, in the other one I didn't get the error.
In the one that crash I have these packages:

```
gdal 1.10.1
numpy 1.7.1
opencv-python 2.4.6
scipy 0.12.0
```

In the one that Works I have:

```
...
gdal 1.9.2
numpy 1.6.2
opencv-python 2.4.3
scipy 0.11.0
...
scikit-image 0.7.2
scikit-learn 0.13.1
scipy 0.11.0
scipy-stack 12.11.29
simplecv 1.3
...
```

And other more. Much more :D. Seems that I miss something but I don't know why it crash with the updated versions. Now I'm installing scipy-stack and scipy and scikit-image...Maybe the error is a missing of packages